# jQuery accordion extending table rows

Tags: jquery, html

I've got basic table of offers like this:

```
<table class="x">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="y">
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Is valid</th>
    <th>Added date</th>
    <th>Expiration date</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title1</td>
      <td>Yes</td>          
      <td>11.09.2017</td>
      <td>30.09.2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title2</td>
      <td>Yes</td>          
      <td>1.10.2017</td>
      <td>2.11.2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title3</td>
      <td>Yes3</td>          
      <td>11.11.2017</td>
      <td>30.12.2017</td>
  </tr>
  (...)
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to add jQuery Accordion which will extend each table row onclick and provide additional information on each offer inside a single div, below the clicked row.
Anyone knows how to do it? I've read shortly accordion API, but no success so far...

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free coding service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. The objective is to help fix **your code**

Comment: @charlietfl okay - you are right, I'm currently searching for solutions. I should ask after I will code anything by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed your code in this fiddle below. 
I just replaced `div` to `tr`.

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fyep7uwk/)

Comment: wow this is very close to which I imagined. Thank you for this code! Only if rows could expand more smoothly vertically...

Answer (score -2):

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  } );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with question? This is nothing more than a copy/paste of a demo from jQuery UI with no explanation

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.